# Problema con ejercicio en java

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package sistemastiquetes;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class SistemasTiquetes {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        String ciudadOrigen,ciudadDestino,nombreCompleto,edad,documentoIdentidad,tipoServicio,horaViaje  = null;

        String destino;

        int valor;
        double valorConIva;
        double costoBase;
        double iva;





       System.out.println(" \t \t \t Transporte CooEste \t \t \t");
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("==================================================");

        System.out.println("Ingrese su ciudad de origen: Medellin, Bogota, Andes, Planeta Rica:");
        ciudadOrigen = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su ciudad de destino: Medellin, Bogota, Andes, Planeta Ricaa:");
        ciudadDestino = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese nombres y apellidos completos:");
        nombreCompleto = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
        edad = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero de documento de identidad:");
        documentoIdentidad = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de vehiculo en el que desea viajar: Minivan, Normal, Especial:");
        tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();


        if (tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Minivan")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 6Am,5Pm,11Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        else if (tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Normal")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 8Am,1Pm,7Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        else if (tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Especial")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 10Am,3Pm,9Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        if (tipoServicio.equals("Minivan")){
        valor = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        } else if (destino.equals ("Medellin - Bogota")|| destino.equals ("Bogota - Medellin")){
         valor = 80000;
        } else if (destino.equals ("Medellin - Andes")|| destino.equals ("Andes - Medellin")){
            valor= 20000;
        } else if (destino.equals ("Medellin - PlanetaRica")|| destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Medellin")){
            valor= 57000;
        } else if (destino.equals ("Bogota - Andes")|| destino.equals ("Andes -Bogota")){
            valor= 63000;
        } else if (destino.equals ("Bogota - PlanetaRica")|| destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Bogota")){
            valor = 150000:
        } else if (destino.equals ("Andes - PlanetaRica")|| destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Andes")){
            valor = 70000;


           int edadIngresada = Integer.valueOf(edad).intValue();
           if (edadIngresada >=1 && edadIngresada <=5){
               costoBase = valor * 0.1;
           } else if (edadIngresada >=5  && edadIngresada <=20){
               costoBase = valor * 0.10:
           } else if (edadIngresada >=20 && edadIngresada <= 40){
               costoBase = valor * 0.5;
           } else if (edadIngresada > 40){
               costoBase = valor * (3.5*100);


           }
```

Recién empiezo a estudiar Ing en sistemas, tengo un trabajo de practica de logica 
tengo un taller el cual no he podido termina y presenta varios errores y no he podido dar con ellos

Comment: Hola rodri133, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y ganes tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hola Rodri. Lee los enlaces que te procura @KacosPro. Tu pregutna no se considera de calidad porque has de explicar lo que pretendes conseguir, y que errores o problemas concretos tienes. Nosotros no podemos depurar por ti. Intenta aclarar y especificar los problemas. un saludo

Answer (score 4):

Varios errores muy obvios.

Terminas varias sentencias con `:` en vez de `;`

Tienes un punto en el que usas `valor = scanner.nextLine()` que devuelve un valor String, no puedes "castear" esto, tienes que usar `sc.nextInt()`.

Te dejo el código solucionado.

Otra aclaración es que el Scanner tiene distintos métodos que devuelven distintos tipos de valores.

> `NextLine() ---- > devuelve String`
>
> `NextInt()  -----> devuelve int`
>
> `NextDouble() ----> devuelve double`

entre otros ejemplos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SistemasTiquetes {

       
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ciudadOrigen,ciudadDestino,nombreCompleto,edad,documentoIdentidad,tipoServicio,horaViaje  = "";
        
        String destino="";
       
        int valor;
        double valorConIva;
        double costoBase;
        double iva;
        
        
        
       
        
       System.out.println(" \t \t \t Transporte CooEste \t \t \t");
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("==================================================");
       
        System.out.println("Ingrese su ciudad de origen: Medellin, Bogota, Andes, Planeta Rica:");
        ciudadOrigen = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su ciudad de destino: Medellin, Bogota, Andes, Planeta Ricaa:");
        ciudadDestino = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombres y apellidos completos:");
        nombreCompleto = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
        edad = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese numero de documento de identidad:");
        documentoIdentidad = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de vehiculo en el que desea viajar: Minivan, Normal, Especial:");
        tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
       
        
        if(tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Minivan")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 6Am,5Pm,11Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        
        else if(tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Normal")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 8Am,1Pm,7Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        
        else if(tipoServicio.equalsIgnoreCase("Especial")){
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Hora de salida: 10Am,3Pm,9Pm: ");
         tipoServicio = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        
        if(tipoServicio.equals("Minivan")){
        valor = scanner.nextInt();
        }else if (destino.equals("Medellin - Bogota")|| destino.equals ("Bogota - Medellin")){
         valor = 80000;
        } else if (destino.equals("Medellin - Andes")|| destino.equals ("Andes - Medellin")){
            valor= 20000;
        } else if (destino.equals("Medellin - PlanetaRica")|| destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Medellin")){
            valor= 57000;
        } else if (destino.equals("Bogota - Andes") || destino.equals ("Andes -Bogota")){
            valor= 63000;
        } else if(destino.equals("Bogota - PlanetaRica") || destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Bogota")){
            valor = 150000;
        } else if (destino.equals("Andes - PlanetaRica") || destino.equals ("PlanetaRica - Andes")){
            valor = 70000;
        
            
           int edadIngresada = Integer.valueOf(edad).intValue();
           if (edadIngresada >=1 && edadIngresada <=5){
               costoBase = valor * 0.1;
           } else if(edadIngresada >=5  && edadIngresada <=20){
               costoBase = valor * 0.10;
           } else if(edadIngresada >=20 && edadIngresada <= 40){
               costoBase = valor * 0.5;
           } else if(edadIngresada > 40){
               costoBase = valor * (3.5*100);
               
               
           }     

        }
    }
    }
```